# Quasi-modified equation for harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Could you help me with this question please?
Find quasi-modified equation of 2nd order for solution of harmonic oscillator equation with semi-explicit Euler(also called symplectic Euler) scheme.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with the terms in the question, especially "quasi-modified equation" (I can guess, but I never heard it called like that). Also show us what you've done so far and the context in which you learned about modified equations. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question for more hints (that still applies even if your question is not homework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got exactly the same question (though in a different language since I'm not studying in the states.)  The best resource I could find is http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/poly_geoint/week3.pdf